# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row when converting from epoch time

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update a table to list YYYY-MM-DD from its current state in epoch time. Here's my attempt:

```
UPDATE Ratings 
SET Timestamps = (
SELECT to_char(to_date('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') + 
numtodsinterval(timestamps,'SECOND'),'YYYY-MM-DD') 
FROM Ratings);
```

But I keep receiving the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

I've read up on the error but I can't figure out why I'm receiving it in this situation. Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a subquery:

```
UPDATE Ratings 
    SET Timestamps = to_char(to_date('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') +  numtodsinterval(timestamps, 'SECOND'),
                             'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

The update is all for fields in a single row.

Comment: UGH! How did I miss such a simple solution? Thanks.